# Bind Collections To Gridview

Tags: asp.net, generics, gridview, collections

```
protected void BindGV()
        {
            List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                new List<string>() {"Hussain","IT","Hyderabad" },
                new List<string>() { "Sharief","IT","Bangalore"},
                new List<string>() { "Shaik","IT","Chennai"}
            };
            gv1.DataSource = list;
            gv1.DataBind();

        }
```

I want to display only Name and City in Gridview. I want to use like:

```
<asp:Boundfield Datafield="" Headertext="Name"/>
```

How to use DataField in this case??

Comment: I am not sure but you can take benefit of linq

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should create a List with some class, rather than string. Then you can use class properties in you DataGrid as columns.

For example:

```
public class Personnel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a data source like:

```
protected void BindGV()
{
    List< Personnel > list = new List< Personal >()
    {
        new Personnel {Name = "Hussain", Department = "IT", Location = "Hyderabad" },
        new Personnel {Name = "Sharief", Department = "IT", Location = "Bangalore"},
        new Personnel {Name = "Shaik",  Department = "IT", Location = "Chennai"}
    };

    gv1.DataSource = list;
    gv1.DataBind();

}
```

In your code behind create DataGrid like

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Dept" DataField="Department" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="Location" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And that should be it.

UPDATE: According to you comment, you want to access `DataField` programatically. You can do this by enumerating `gv1.Columns` property and then cast the result to `BoundColumn`. This will give you access to `DataField` and other properties.

Comment: Yes, I know the above given  approach. But I want to know how to access the Datafiled in this case?

Comment: To access DataField programatically? If that is the case check my Update part.

Answer (score 1):

as Husein said, first create class with Get , Set .
like

```
Public class BindGV
{
    public string name { get; set ;}
    public string Profile { get; set ;}
    public string loc { get; set ;}
}
```

In aspx page Gridview BoundField....

```
<ItemTemplate..>
    <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Title") %> </b>
    <br />
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Description") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

... Or Apsx.cs code

```
BindGV.datasource=object.GetDetails();
BindGV.dataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of linq

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>()
                              {
                                 new List<string>() {"Hussain", "IT", "Hyderabad"},
                                 new List<string>() {"Sharief", "IT", "Bangalore"},
                                 new List<string>() {"Shaik", "IT", "Chennai"}
                              };
```

linq query

```
var v = from li in list select new {Name = li[0], City=li[2]};
gv1.DataSource = v;
gv1.DataBind();
```

And gridview

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="False>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="City" />
 </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

But this is not a good Idea to use.
You should have a proper structure of you property as suggested by the two gentle men.